# No duplication: 'Are there portable Reverse Osmosis water systems for long-term travellers staying in apartments?'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

It is unclear why [How to always have Reverse Osmosis filtered water when travelling between apartments with varying plumbing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/91209/13759) was closed 'as duplicate' of [Are there portable non-electrical water filters that filter chemicals, metals, and pathogens?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79496/13759).

The latter recommends something to which the former replies as being unhelpful, as explained [in my comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91209/are-there-portable-reverse-osmosis-water-systems-for-long-term-travellers-stayin/91221#comment218379_91209).

Comment: I still don't understand the difference - isn't your title asking for the same exact thing? Why does the recommendation inside the post matter?

Comment: @JonathanReez I do not comprehend how the differences have not been understood? The former (specifying RO and apartments) is more specific than the latter.

Comment: If it's not a dup, then [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) seems to apply ...

Comment: @brhans No it doesn't, it's asking if something exists which meets certain clear criteria - "I have a travel problem with my water, is there anything that can solve it?". It would apply if it was something like "Which portable Reverse Osmosis system [should I buy / is the best / is cheapest / etc]"

Comment: So you're asking for a simple "Yes, this thing exists" or "No, this thing does not exist" as an answer? Seems unlikely. In any case, the final line in Harpers's answer to your 2nd question seems to be applicable - "get good at adapters.". If you want RO, you need pressure. Pressure either comes from attaching securely to the faucet, or using a pump. You don't want an electric pump - so that leaves attaching to the faucet - with adapters as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see why they looked similar and why some people mistakenly assumed you were re-asking the question because you didn't like the previous answer:

- One is a travel tech question, asking if any system exists that does what reverse osmosis does, for people travelling across North America and elsewhere
- The other is written like a travel tech question, asking if any system exists that does reverse osmosis, suitable for this person travelling across part of North America

...but looking at it more closely, I think **the difference is**:

- One is a straightforward: "What sort of technology achieves this standard of water quality"?

  - Answer: Reverse osmosis, with example
- The other appears to be: "I was trying to solve a travel problem using a reverse osmosis system, but I've run into a snag because of incompatible valves. How can I get around this problem?"

  - Possible answer: some sort of valve adapter, allowing a standard reverse osmosis system to be used anywhere
  - Possible answer: some service providing pre-filtered water refills, eliminating the need for the reverse osmisis system (without causing lots of plastic waste)
  - Possible answer: some alternate reverse osmosis system with a more flexible attachment system

It's more of a problem solving question than a travel tech/gear question, so I've edited the title to make that more obvious and I've voted to re-open it.

Comment: +1. Thank you. You have discerned the difference!